# Show only last path or url string [Tableau]

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to get the last path name in a url string in tableau.

"~/**blah1**"

"~/blah1/**blah2**"

"~/blah1/blah2/**blah3**"

I've tried `Mid([Pages],1,Find([Pages],'/')-1)` but that did the opposite and gave me just "~".

Any help is much appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex in a Tableau formula, for example REGEX_EXTRACT(), with the following to extract everything after the last '/':

(?!.*/).+

Your Tableau formula will look similar to the following:

**REGEX_EXTRACT([URL], '(?!.*/).+')**

Answer (score 1):

This should work -

```
SPLIT( [Pages], "/", -1 )
```

This returns a substring from the Page string, using the "/" delimiter character to divide the string into a sequence of tokens.

> The string is interpreted as an alternating sequence of delimiters and
>   tokens. So for the string abc-defgh-i-jkl, where the delimiter
>   character is ‘-‘, the tokens are abc, defgh, i and jlk. Think of these
>   as tokens 1 through 4. SPLIT returns the token corresponding to the
>   token number. When the token number is positive, tokens are counted
>   starting from the left end of the string; when the token number is
>   negative, tokens are counted starting from the right. -
>   [Tableau String Functions](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-gb/functions_functions_string.htm)